# Android - Upload bmp to server using Multipart fails

Tags: android, retrofit, multipart

I'm trying to upload a bmp file to server (avatar). To do so I'm suing Retrofit and Multipart. Here's retrofit part :

```
@Multipart
    @POST("api/media/images")
    suspend fun uploadImage(
        @Part file: MultipartBody.Part?
    ): UploadImageResponse
```

Users picks one image from gallery and then app should upload it to server. I'm using jetpack compose in this app. Here's my component to select a photo :

```
@Composable
fun UploadButton(bitmapSelected: MutableState<Bitmap?>) {

    var imageUri by remember {
        mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null)
    }

    val context = LocalContext.current

    val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract =
        ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()
    ) { uri: Uri? ->
        imageUri = uri
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(72.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top
    ) {
        IconButton(
            modifier = Modifier
                .clip(CircleShape)
                .size(48.dp)
                .background(Color.Black),
            onClick = { launcher.launch("image/*") })
        {
            imageUri?.let { it ->
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 28) {
                    bitmapSelected.value = MediaStore.Images
                        .Media.getBitmap(context.contentResolver, it)

                } else {
                    val source = ImageDecoder
                        .createSource(context.contentResolver, it)
                    bitmapSelected.value = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
                    bitmapSelected.value = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
                }
                bitmapSelected.value?.let { btm ->
                    Image(
                        bitmap = btm.asImageBitmap(),
                        contentDescription = null,
                        modifier = Modifier.size(40.dp),
                        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
                    )
                }
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(PaddingSmall))
        }
        Text(
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            text = stringResource(R.string.upload_profile_photo),
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2,
            color = Color.Black
        )
    }
}
```

as you can see the state is passed to Screen Composable class when selected bmp is used:

```
@Composable
fun CreateAccountScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: CreateAccountViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
...
val bitmap = remember {mutableStateOf<Bitmap?>(null) }
    UploadButton( bitmapSelected = bitmap  )
```

Everything works great. You can pick photo and set it as avatar. However , when I want to send photo as Part to backend like this :

```
fun bitmapToMultipart(imageBitmap: Bitmap): MultipartBody.Part {
    val bos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos)
    val bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray()
    Log.i(TAG, "bitmapToMultipart: ${Base64.encodeToString(bitmapdata,Base64.NO_WRAP)}")

    val name: RequestBody = bitmapdata.toRequestBody("image/*".toMediaTypeOrNull(), 0, bitmapdata.size)
    return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", "avatar", name)
}
```

I'm reciving an error from server that this is not an image. What can be wrong ? Where's an issue ?

Comment: Try using a concrete MIME type, not a wildcard (`image/*`).

Comment: Can you show me an example please ?

Comment: You are encoding your image as JPEG (`imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos)`). The MIME type for JPEG is `image/jpeg`, not `image/*`.

Comment: `val bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray()` ? Or `val jpgdata = bos.toByteArray()` ? You are not uploading a bitmap but a jpg file.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I had to add .jpg to file name so it should be :

```
return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", "avatar.jpg", name)
```